# Не работает jquery скрипт в WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Собственно сам код http://pastebin.com/30k5fG2C
CSS подключаю так

```
 wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', plugins_url("assets/css/style.css", __FILE__));
   wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', plugins_url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css", __FILE__));
```

но слайдер почему-то не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Первый аргумент функции `wp_enqueue_style()` интерпретируется как атрибут `id` тега `style`, так что он должен быть уникален.
Кроме того, не нужно использовать функцию `plugins_url` во второй строке, ведь у вас внешняя ссылка.

Попробуйте так:

```
wp_enqueue_style('my-styles-1', plugins_url("assets/css/style.css", __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```